screen scroolback scrolling buffer. defscrollback 10000 didn't work
I would like to increase the scrolling buffer of screen.
In screen, I modified .screenrc with
defscrollback 10000

to increase the scrolling buffer, but nothing has changed.
What was done wrong?
This is my .screenrc
defscrollback 10000
logfile /path/to/your/logfile.log
log on

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session

since this works when you specify the scrollback buffer height on the command line (screen -h 10000), first step I'd take is send a bug report to screen-devel@gnu.org. These things are, per documentation, supposed to be identical in effect.
Then, what really happens is, reading src/process.c from the screen source code,
static void DoCommandDefscrollback(struct action *act)
{
    (void)ParseNum(act, &nwin_default.histheight);
}

what that means is that the command has no effect on the current window, just on subsequently created ones. You can try – open a new window from your current screen session (ctrl+a   c), and it should have the desired scrollback buffer.
Solutions:

always start screen with  -h 10000 (you could make that easier by having a alias screen=screen -h 10000 in your shell's RC)
add the creation of a new window, and the deletion of the first window to your .screenrc (probably undesirable, because that first window would be the one running commands you specified as argument to screen).
go and figure out how to teach screen to reallocate the scrollback buffer for an existing window. I'd call that a bit of an exercise in C.


Muller, when I tried screen -h 10000 it has the same default short buffer.

@MichaelD huh, that worked for me!

the way I checked was: 1. screen -h 10000 2. run python loop which prints 10K lines: for i in range(1000): print(i).
